# Remove Item From List if Found in Python

Tags: python, list, remove-if

How can i remove an item from a list if it is found to match another item from another list?

```
for item in bigIpList:
    for item2 in smallIpList:
        if item==item2:
            #remove item from bigIpList
```

Comment: `new_list = [ip for ip in bigIpList if ip in smallIpList]`.

Comment: @Rogalski That is the opposite of what the OP wants to do. That removes the elements he wants to keep. It should be `bigIpList = [item for item in bigIpList if item not in smallIpList]`

Comment: @mbomb007 your comment worked

Answer (score 0):

use filter:

```
bigIpList = filter(lambda e: e not in smallIpList, bigIpList)
```